# How to chown all root directory to root

Tags: root, chown

I accidentally set the whole of / to another user other than root and it messed up sudo etc. I managed to get sudo back but how do I reset everything else? Back to root.

Comment: There is no way. Reinstall.

Comment: All files and directories are not and should not be owned by root. It will be very very difficult to revert to the old state. I recommend backing up your important files and doing a complete re-install.

Comment: Please reinstall **without** formatting. It will be the quickest and most secure method. Before that do make a backup when you booted from the live session